# When will RPG.SE come out of beta?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

According to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2208/role-playing-games), we've been in beta way more than a year now.  All [our stats on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2208/role-playing-games) aren't always green, but they've sure been consistent over that time. What is required for us to move ahead?  There's only two sites in beta older than we are, and some of the launched sites have stats virtually identical to ours (e.g. [Home Improvement](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/170/home-improvement)).

Edit: As an update, we still haven't heard from anyone on the community team or CHAOS. So we're left to our own devices to get site stats up to the point where someone might decide to care about us. I will note that the gaming renaissance on Google+ is making it our largest referring site now. Over the year our traffic has gone up and down but it looks like a good 25% improvement page view wise; questions and answers are flat. Basically if you read this and care, you can help by promoting the site via links on forums, blogs (yours and others), twitter, g+, fb, etc.

Comment: Related but a cruel lie apparently: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/492/when-is-the-site-going-to-be-out-of-beta

Comment: [status-completed] ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/

> Can you tell us when we’ll graduate?
>
> Unfortunately, we are not yet able to predict when a site will reach critical mass. A large part of this summer will be spent looking at the traffic data we’ve accumulated over the last three years to make sense of it all.
>
> If your traffic indicators aren’t dropping precipitously, that’s a good sign. If your traffic is falling, we’ll let you know through meta initiatives.

Related:

- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/rpg.stackexchange.com
- http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#rpg.stackexchange.com
- diamond moderator admin analytics panel

Comment: Right, and our stats have been constant for a long, long time now. So either these numbers are OK and we may as well get graduated (and like I say, others with equivalent stats did like HI), or they're not and we should be cancelled, but I doubt another year of hanging around in beta will change a thing - stats have levelled off as of like April. Time to do *something.*

Comment: As a tangent, the stats available to non-diamond mods are pretty useless. Hooray, we have numbers! Some of them are green (I guess that's good, maybe?), some of them are red (which is a lovely color, I guess). Are they as red as they were last month? I don't remember! I guess I have no real idea what we're supposed to be getting out of them, especially since they get linked fairly often.

Comment: The mod stats are more detailed but in this case aren't much more interesting, our stats are spiky but consistent month to month.

Comment: @mxyzplk perhaps solicit some CHAOS team assistance? That team is designed to help grow your site by finding new interested audiences and getting them to your door.

Comment: A merge with [Board & Card Games](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) (to become "Tabletop Games" or something along those lines) perhaps should be considered. (Discussed [here](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/563/is-boardgames-stackexchange-com-a-suitable-url-for-a-board-and-card-games-site/594#594) on B&CG.SE's meta.)

Comment: Strongly disagree with the merge idea - the hobbies are not significantly related, there's even a WotC survey demonstrating crossover between RPGs and board/card is less than with computer and other kinds of gaming.  We'll ping the CHAOS team (start with Cartiano I assume?) I still feel like our stats are steady, other sites have gone live at our level of stats, time to crap or get off the pot.

Comment: @mxyzplk: While you're at it, can you get them to throw some love at B&CG.SE too then? :)

Comment: @adamjford: Love to, but no word back to us yet.

Answer (score 4):

To add on to the blog post Jeff linked to, we look at the overall picture of what the trends we see in a site.  When I look at the traffic stats, I want to see a graph that shows the site is growing - a positive slope to the graph as it gets higher the farther right it goes.  As the blog post mentions, this "tipping point" is vital.  Focus on making this a healthy community and the stats will follow.

Comment: If growth is the important stat to follow, could we get that added to the dashboard here (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/rpg.stackexchange.com)?